# How the Lagrangian is obtained in the given example?

Tags: convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, duality-theorems

In my work which is related to user association with cellphone towers, I had the following optimization problem:

$$
\begin{array}{clc}
& \max\limits_{x_{mk}} \sum\limits_{m=1}^M \sum\limits_{k=0}^K x_{mk} \log \left(R_m^k\right) - \sum\limits_{k=0}^K N_k \log (N_k), & (12) \\
\mathrm{s.t.} &\sum\limits_{k=0}^K x_{mk} = 1, \; x_{mk} \in \{0, 1\}, \; \forall m,k, & (13) \\
& \sum\limits_{m=1}^M x_{mk} = N_k, \; k = 0,1,...,K, & (14) \\
& \sum\limits_{m=1}^M x_{mk} R_m^k \leq N_k R_k^0, \; k=1,2,...,K. & (15)
\end{array}
$$

Then the Lagrangian dual problem is written as

$$
\begin{array}{clc}
& \max\limits_{x_{mk}, N_k} \sum\limits_{m=1}^M \sum\limits_{k=0}^K x_{mk} \left(\log \left(R_m^k\right) - \lambda_{1, k} - \lambda_{2, k} R_m^k\right) + \\ & + \sum\limits_{k=0}^K \left(-N_K \log(N_k) + \lambda_{1,k}N_k + \lambda_{2, k} R_k^{0} N_k\right), & (16) \\
\mathrm{s.t.} &\sum\limits_{k=0}^K x_{mk} = 1, & (17) \\
& x_{mk} \in [0, 1]. & (18)
\end{array}
$$

where $\lambda_{1,k}$ and $\lambda_{2,k}$ are Lagrangian multipliers for constraint $(14)$ and $(15)$ respectively.

My query is how the eq $(16)$ is obtained from eq $(12-15)$. I had tried obtaining, but my all terms are not matching with the equation $(16)$.

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: It looks ok to me (I could be wrong). Remember that the (14) contributes $\sum_k \lambda_{1,k} ( \sum_m (N_k - x_{mk}))$ and (15) contributes $\sum_k \lambda_{2,k} ( N_k R^0_k - \sum_m x_{mk} R^k_m )$.

Comment: I didn't notice before, but this is an integer programming problem, I am not sure what relevance a Lagrangian has here?

Comment: Thank you so much sir for your response....in the paper (from where these equation are taken) the Lagrangian is used...by the way could you please tell how eq (14) and eq (15) contributes to those which you had mentioned in your previous  comment.

Comment: The Lagrangian is the sum of the cost and the two terms in my comment above. I presume you were asking if the computations are correct and they seem to be, to me.

Comment: Yes sir...I was asking regarding the same...But I am not getting the correct answer ....Can u please show the steps for those computations so that I understand where I am making the mistake...

Comment: Just collect terms, it really is not difficult. My first term above should be $\sum_k \lambda_{1,k} (N_k -  \sum_m x_{mk})$

Comment: Yes sir.... I am solving that problem only ...once I get the solution I will post here...I had one request to you that please check my steps and let me know whether my steps and hence my understanding is correct or not....

Comment: Sir, As per my understanding from Prof. Boyd book, to form Lagrangian equation for maximizing optimization problem, we write the original optimization problem minus Lagrangian multiplier times the constraint. So here I had done as : Lagrangian = $ \underset{x_{mk},N_k}{\text{max}} \sum_{m}\sum_{k}x_{mk}\text{log}(R_m^k)-\sum_k N_k \text{log}(N_k)-\lambda_{1,k}\biggl(\sum_m x_{mk}-N_k\biggr)-\lambda_{2,k}\biggl(\sum_m x_{mk}R_m^k-N_kR_k^0\biggr)$ and after that if we do some simplification like taking $\sum_m x_{mk}$ as common we get the eq (16). Is my answer and understanding correct sir.....

Comment: Can u please check it sir whether my answer is correct or not....

Comment: You need to do your own double checking. It is not difficult.